# Tutorial on integrating CG shader into GL and D3D9?

Tags: c++, opengl, direct3d, cg

I've found many tutorials on writing CG shaders but none that show how to integrate it into a D3D or GL scene. Is there a tutorial that would show how CG would integrate into these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this on iOS/Android OpenGL ES 2.0, but this could work for you too: [hlsl2glslfork](https://github.com/aras-p/hlsl2glslfork). It's a library that you can compile/link right into you application, and it can translate your Cg/HLSL to GLSL right before you call `glShaderSource`.

Comment: He is speaking of integrating Cg into GL and DX (which is achievable without problems) and you suggest him to switch the shading language (so now he cannot use the same shader for GL and DX anymore).

Comment: I am not suggesting he switch languages at all. hlsl2glslfork allows you to translate the code on-the-fly in your application. He can author his code in Cg, and then translate to GLSL right before calling glShaderSource. hlsl2glslfork can be linked right into your application.

Comment: Ah, sorry then. Although still a bit off-topic (only a bit), the answer is much more interresting and useful now. You should include that in your answer.

Comment: Hence the "this could work for you", depending on which direction he wanted to go in. For instance, on iOS (which I recognize he didn't ask about), you can't use Cg in OpenGL, so you have no other option. But even if you do, it might be nicer to pass OpenGL native GLSL if, say, your drivers have better compilers for GLSL, so translating it is the option. I'll add to my answer as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codesampler.com/oglsrc/oglsrc_10.htm#ogl_cg_simple_vs2ps - This sample might help you.
http://developer.nvidia.com/node/91 - You can also read this.